Shading issue in EEVEE
I dont know what to do. I'm using a simple Cel shader that I've always used and these weird shadows started appeared. I never saw them before. it looks like a Normals issue but resetting vectors don't work. Is there a better more sofistacated design I should be using, am I using a redundant node?[

Have you tried merging vertices by distance and checking for internal geometry?

Yes. I tried that as well as checking for extra faces hiding.

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

I had shadows turned on in the sun light properties, on accident. 
